# Prepared statement not executing in node js with mssql

Tags: javascript, sql-server, node.js, asynchronous, prepared-statement

After I run the code, all I get is the console log "Done.", with nothing updated in the database. What am I doing wrong?

```
var pool = new sql.ConnectionPool(config);
var ps = new sql.PreparedStatement(pool);

ps.input('code', sql.VarChar);
ps.input('hex', sql.VarChar);

ps.prepare("UPDATE tHE_SetItem SET acPicture = CONVERT(varbinary(max), @hex, 2) WHERE acIdent = @code;", function(err) {

    async.mapSeries(hexes, function(pair, next) {

        ps.execute({code: pair.code, hex: pair.hex}, next);

    }, function(err) {

        ps.unprepare(function(err) {

            console.log("Done!");

        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Have you tried logging `err`? Clearly the error callback seems to be executing so it would make sense to try that.

Comment: @Script47 Damn... You are right. This is what you get for working 12 hours straight. Simple things pass you by. Thank you for the slap to the head. This lead me to realize that I am not actually connecting with `pool.connect()`

Comment: Eh, take a break, work is not that important.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comment, I left out the error callbacks, which in turn notified me that I was not actually making a connection. Here is the revised code.

```
var pool = new sql.ConnectionPool(config);
pool.connect().then(function(){ // <------------- This in particular
    var i = 0;
    var ps = new sql.PreparedStatement(pool);
    ps.input('code', sql.VarChar);
    ps.input('hex', sql.VarChar);
    ps.prepare("UPDATE tHE_SetItem SET acPicture = CONVERT(varbinary(max), @hex, 2) WHERE acIdent = @code;", function(err) {
        if(err) console.log(err);
        async.mapSeries(hexes, function(pair, next) {
            i++;
            console.log(i + "/" + hexes.length + " " + Math.round(i / hexes.length * 100) + "% - " + pair.code);
            ps.execute({code: pair.code, hex: pair.hex}, next);
        }, function(err) {
            if(err) console.log(err);
            ps.unprepare(function(err) {
                if(err) console.log(err);
                console.log("Done!");
            });
        });
    });
}).catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```